# unable to git clone by symbol lookup error: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libp11-kit.so.0: undefined symbol: ffi_type_pointer, version LIBFFI_BASE_7.0

Tags: git, ubuntu, package

Reproduce:

`git clone [any repo with https link]`

Error:

`/usr/lib/git-core/git-remote-https: symbol lookup error: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libp11-kit.so.0: undefined symbol: ffi_type_pointer, version LIBFFI_BASE_7.0`

I have tried:

1. remove and reinstall git.
2. remove the libbp11-kit and `wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libf/libffi/libffi7_3.3-4_amd64.deb` then install another one.

None of them works

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you are using a conda environment, then installing `git` through `conda install` solved the above error.

```
conda install -c anaconda git
```

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem by finding that
In one of my conda envs
When I entered the lib directory, and use

```
ls -l | grep libffi
```

Just found that some version 8 is linked to version 7.
Then I removed the conda env
And the problem was solved.

Answer (score 1):

Just experienced a similar issue, try these steps.
Adding a PPA with:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:git--core/ppa
```

Then update to latest git version with:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install git
```

Add your git config details if you have not done so already

```
git config --global user.name "Your Name"
git config --global user.email "youremail@domain.com"
```

Then run your `git clone...` again

Comment: Follow this https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/5491#issuecomment-650506906 if use Ubuntu

Comment: but the problem still not solved btw